# In angularjs how can I log exception and stacktrace, users gets in production?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, stack-trace

I have try to override:

```
.factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($log, logger) {
    return function (exception, cause, more) {
         aLoggerServiceIDefined.error(exception, cause);
    };
})
```

1. how can I get more meaningful exceptions?
2. How can I get the stacktrace?

For the stacktrace I tried to use stacktrace.js, but it doesn't give me the original trace when where the exception happen, but only the current stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you use stacktrace simply use this format:

```
var trace = printStackTrace({e: lastError});
```

Also, I would use a decorator instead of overriding $exceptionHandler (see [How to override $exceptionHandler implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595469/how-to-override-exceptionhandler-implementation)):
For example, in coffeescript:

```
$provide.decorator "$exceptionHandler", ($delegate) ->
  (exception, cause) ->
    $delegate(exception, cause)
    trace = printStackTrace({e: exception})
    console.debug("Trace:#{trace} \nCause: #{cause}")
```

Comment: I know this answer is old, but where is `printStackTrace` defined?