# Injecting $http into angular factory($exceptionHandler) results in a Circular dependency

Tags: angularjs, circular-dependency

When I try inject $http into an overridden factory I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <-
>   $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope

```
AngularModule.factory('$exceptionHandler',  function ($http) {
```

any ideas how to resolve? if I inject using [], $http is undefined

edit_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

as per an answer below I tried:

```
MyModule.config(function($provide, $http) {
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate) {
        return function(exception, cause) {..
```

but I still get the circular error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <-
>   $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope

Comment: I am not sure why do you inject $http into a core factory? No wonder you get a circular DI. Perhaps create a custom factory in which you inject both $exceptionHandler and $http ?

Comment: @AlexC well by default I just want to use $http to log serverside..

Comment: .factory('My',  function () {
               
           })
           .factory('$exceptionHandler',  function ($log,My) {
               
           }) works if you pass $http on My I get Error: [$injector:cdep] http://errors.

Comment: @FutuToad would `$decorate` be the right thing here, if you're trying to overload the functionality of something like `$log`?

Comment: @c0bra yeah, can you check my edit

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inject the `$injector` and then get the `$http` service from there. Something like this:

```
AngularModule.factory('$exceptionHandler',  function ($injector) {
    var $http = $injector.get("$http");
```

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/lbFY_14ZtnU/discussion

However, this will completely override the `$exceptionHandler` functionality provided by Angular. If you just want to add the server-side log to the existing functionality, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595469/how-to-override-exceptionhandler-implementation/16942964) about augmenting `$exceptionHandler` functionality.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do this either: **var $http = $injector.get("$http");** I get the error **$http <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope**

Comment: I don't think the circular dependency is coming from the $injector. I've gotten around many circular dependencies by getting them straight from the $injector. Make sure you still aren't trying to wire in $http anywhere in this $exceptionHandler stuff.

Comment: thanks, you mean like this: $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate,$injector) {
        return function(exception, cause) {
            var $http = $injector.get("$http");

Comment: that way seems to work, I get the $http function, but for some reason though when I try the **$http.get().always**, I get TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'always'

Comment: @FutuToad I think dnc253 is right. Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ilJj4?p=preview  Also, $q has `finally`, not `always`.

Comment: @c0bra thanks, got a bit confused as I saw complete somewhere in the docs

Comment: This works, but only if you don't minify the code, which screws over the references here.

Comment: If minifying the code, you have to use the array notation just like anywhere else. (`['$injector', function ($injector) { ...`)

Comment: For me `var $http = $injector.get("$http");` actually didn't work, it was still resolving the dependency too soon. A simple, albeit also not pretty, alternative is to do `$injector.get("$http").get(....);` in the actual logic.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this solution, because of circular dependency issues with rootScope:

```
angular
  .module('facilityLog')
  .provider('$exceptionHandler', function() {
 "use strict";

 this.$get = function($injector) {

  function exceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
   // This is the part where you get the instance of $http in your case
   var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
   //...
  }

  return exceptionHandler;

}});
```

So if you request the instance inside the exceptionHandler-Function you will not get the circular dependency-error.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to solve this. Note how the array notation is used to make this minification safe.
Note also, that I am completely overriding the $esceptionHandler and using my own service to replace it.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('$exceptionHandler', $exceptionHandler);

$exceptionHandler.$inject = ['$injector', 'exceptionLoggingService'];

function $exceptionHandler($injector, exceptionLoggingService)
{
    return function(exception, cause)
    {
        exceptionLoggingService.http = exceptionLoggingService.http || $injector.get('$http');
        exceptionLoggingService.error(exception, cause);
    };
}
```