# Circular Reference when decorating $errorProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, circular-dependency

On a project I'm working on, I'm working on implementing a developer notification system at my project lead's behest.  The way it works, is that if a front-end error occurs, the development team gets sent an error e-mail.

However, with my current implementation, it seems I have the following circular dependency:

`$rootScope <- $http <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope`

In the following code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Using .config to 'decorate' the exception handler.
    angular.module('app').config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$http', dispatchErrorEmail]);
    });

    function dispatchErrorEmail($delegate, $http) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            // Execute default implementation.
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            // Angular exceptions fail softly, but generate an error email.
            var args = {
                'exception': exception,
                'cause': cause
            };
            $http.post('/api/admin/ErrorNotification', args);
        };
    }
})();
```

As you can see, there's one *small* problem: **I'm not actually using `$rootScope` in any way whatsoever in my decoration of `$errorHandler`.**

What's more, neither the `$provide.decorator` or the `$errorHandler` documentation makes any note of `$rootScope` being implicitly included.

**Questions:**

1. How is `$rootScope` getting injected into this service, exactly?
2. In what way can I rewrite my `$exceptionHandler` decoration to avoid this circular dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little additional looking around - specifically, on the **Related** sidebar - led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332130/injecting-http-into-angular-factoryexceptionhandler-results-in-a-circular-de?rq=1).  Pretty much, I have to use `$injector` in order to get an instance handle of my `$http` service.

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

    // Using .config to 'decorate' the exception handler.
    angular.module('app').config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$injector', dispatchErrorEmail]);
    });

    function dispatchErrorEmail($delegate, $injector) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            // Execute default implementation.
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            // Angular exceptions fail softly, but generate an error email.
            var $http = $injector.get('$http');
            var args = {
                'exception': exception,
                'cause': cause
            };
            $http.post('/api/admin/ErrorNotification', args);
        };
    }
})();
```

This doesn't explain *why* `$rootScope` is sneaking into the `$exceptionHandler` service; I guess I just have to take it on faith that it does.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and your post helped me find a solution. I have a common library that I use for pretty much all my common page activities like showing toast and managing the loading indicator. You solution helped to access that service using the injector. Hope this helps someone else!

```
// custom exception handling
module.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$injector', function ($delegate, $injector) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            var common = $injector.get('common');
            common.toast('Whoops, an error occurred!');
            common.loading(false);
        };
    }]);
});
```