# Angular - circular dependency injector whie trying inject $modal to exception handler decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui, angularjs-service

Due to [John Papa - 10 AngularJS Patterns presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlvCbnKAH3g) advices I try to implement additional functionality to exception handling:

```
exceptionHandlerDecorator.$inject = ['$provide'];
function exceptionHandlerDecorator($provide){
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', handleException);
}

handleException.$inject = ['$delegate', 'ExceptionHandlerService'];

function handleException($delegate, ExceptionHandlerService){
    function handle(exception, cause){
        $delegate(exception, cause);
        ExceptionHandlerService.handle(exception.message);
    }

    return handle;
}

ExceptionHandlerService.$inject = ['$modal'];

function ExceptionHandlerService($modal){
    //do things
}
```

But when I try ti inject `$modal` to `ExceptionHandlerService` from Angular UI Bootstrap I got [Error: $injector:cdep Circular Dependency](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep?p0=$rootScope%20%3C-%20$modal%20%3C-%20ExceptionHandlerService%20%3C-%20$exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20$rootScope%20%3C-%20$translate) which terrified me. I tried to use accepted solution from very similar question, [Injecting $http into angular factory($exceptionHandler) results in a Circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22332717/3368498):

```
function ExceptionHandlerService($window, $injector){
    var $modal = $injector.get('$modal')
}
```

But it gave me exactly the same result - `Error: $injector:cdep Circular Dependency`. Has anyone had similar problem and knows the solution? Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: When you tried the solution, did you remove the line `ExceptionHandlerService.$inject = ['$modal'];` ?

Comment: @Ian Yes, I removed this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that even if you do,

```
function ExceptionHandlerService($window, $injector){
    var $modal = $injector.get('$modal')
}
```

It will try to instantiate `$modal` service as the ExceptionHandlerService is instantiated via decorator, so it will cause cDep error. You would want to instead get the `$modal` instance lazily when needed and *must not try to instantiate it (or get it) during the service instantiation process*. i.e:

```
 function ExceptionHandlerService($window, $injector){

        function _getModal(){
           //You can afford to do this everytme as service is a singleton and
           //the IOC container will have this instance always once instantiated as it will just act asa getter.
           return $injector.get('$modal');
        }

        function logStuff(){
            _getModal().modal(....
        }
    }
```