# Chicken and egg issue with dependency injection in angular, $exceptionHandler and $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm enjoying a nice chicken and egg problem with dependancy injection in angular,  I override $exceptionHandler by injecting $http, but I also have a custom interceptor.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:  $httpProvider <-  $http <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope
```

I am trying to use it like so:

```
Module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('special-http');
}]);
```

I wrapped my interceptor in a factory:

```
Module.factory('special-http', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    'request': function(config) {

      if ($templateCache.get(config.url)){
        return config;
      }

     //some logic

      return config;
    }
  }
}]);
```

exceptionHandler.js

```
Module.factory('$exceptionHandler', [' $http', function ($http) {
    "use strict";
//code
}
```

Comment: please add jsfiddle or full code example.

Comment: My magical crystal ball is telling me that you forgot to inject $http whereever the heck you wanted it to use

Comment: @AlexChoroshin its a massive app so not really, it was working before in the default and expect way

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of creating [interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) .

**Example:**

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
            return {
             'request': function(config) {
                 // same as above
              },

              'response': function(response) {
                 // same as above
              }
            };
          }); 
    }]);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/mxk92/

Comment: I think mine should work the same, can you check my edit. This code was working before but for some reason deploying it on a new server is causing this issue..

Comment: your code is the same as mine and probably some server error