# How to cancel a promise with $q in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, cancellation

I have a service below. I will call this service every time when I open a model and when I close the model and then open another one the previous values are getting reflected and in this case I want to cancel the promise every time I close the model.

I have tried the following code,

Model closing.js

```
$scope.closeButton = function() {
    DetailDataSvc.storeDefer().resolve()
}
```

My Service, (DetailDataSvc)

```
self.storeDefer = function() {
    return self.deferReturn;
};

self.getDetailReportData = function(postData, functionName) {
    var promises = {};

    var d = $q.defer(),
        metricDataType;
    self.deferReturn = $q.defer();
    promises = {
        detailReport: metricDataType,
        recommendedMetrics: DataSvc.getData(_logPrefix + functionName, recommendedMetricUrl),
        metricInfo: DataSvc.getData(_logPrefix + functionName, metricInfoUrl)
    };
    $q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
        $log.debug(_logPrefix + 'getDetailReportData(). Called from %s. $q.all Response (raw): ', functionName, res);
        else {
            if (response && !_.isEmpty(_.get(response, 'largeCard.chartData.dataValues.rows')) && response.overlayEnabled) {
                self.getMetricOverLay(pdata, functionName).then(function(overlayData) {
                    response.largeCard.chartData.overlay = overlayData;
                    d.resolve(response);
                }, function(msg, code) {
                    d.reject(msg);
                    $log.error(_logPrefix + 'getDetailReportData().   Error code: %s.  Error: ', code, msg);
                });
            } else {
                d.resolve(response);
            }
        }


    }, function(msg, code) {
        d.reject(msg);
        $log.error(_logPrefix + 'getDetailReportData().   Error code: %s.  Error: ', code, msg);
    });

    return d.promise;

};
```

Can anyone please help me whether the process I followed is the right one.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2):

What you have attempted could be made to work but it's best fixed by racing the promise returned by `$q.all()` against a rejectable Deferred (ie. a Deferred, of which a reference is kept to its reject method), thus avoiding the [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

```
self.getDetailReportData = function(postData, functionName) {
    var metricDataType = ......; // ???
    var d = $q.defer();

    // cancel previous
    if(self.cancelDetailReport) {
        self.cancelDetailReport(new Error('previous getDetailReportData() cancelled'));
    }
    // keep a reference to the deferred's reject method for next time round.
    self.cancelDetailReport = d.reject;

    var promises = {
        'detailReport': metricDataType,
        'recommendedMetrics': DataSvc.getData(_logPrefix + functionName, recommendedMetricUrl),
        'metricInfo': DataSvc.getData(_logPrefix + functionName, metricInfoUrl)
    };

    // Race aggregated `promises` against `d.promise`, thus providing the required cancellation effect.
    return $q.race([$q.all(promises), d.promise])
    .then(function(response) {
        // arrive here only if all promises resolve and d.reject() has not been called.
        $log.debug(_logPrefix + 'getDetailReportData(). Called from %s. $q.all Response (raw): ', functionName, response);
        if (response && !_.isEmpty(_.get(response, 'largeCard.chartData.dataValues.rows')) && response.overlayEnabled) {
            return self.getMetricOverLay(pdata, functionName)
            .then(function(overlayData) {
                response.largeCard.chartData.overlay = overlayData;
                return response;
            });
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(msg, code) { // signature?
        // all error cases including cancellation end up here.
        var message = _logPrefix + `getDetailReportData().   Error: (${code}): ${msg}`; // or similar
        $log.error(message);
        throw new Error(message); // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250798/3478010
    });
};
```

Notes:

1. `$q.race()` is transparent to whichever promise wins the race, and opaque to the other. So, if the `d` is rejected before the promise returned by `$q.all()` settles, then `d` will win out; `response` handling will not happen and d's rejection will fall through to the `.catch()` clause. Alternatively, if the promise returned by `$q.all(promises)` wins out then flow will follow that promise's success path (ie `response` handling) or possibly its error path (which will drop through to the `.catch()` clause).
2. Not too sure about the signature of the `.catch()` callback. You would normally expect it to accept a single `error` argument.

Comment: FYI With [AngularJS V1.5.8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#158-arbitrary-fallbacks-2016-07-22), the $q Service now has the `.race` method as well.

Comment: @georgeawg, thank you, that makes a big difference to this exercise. I'll check it out and edit my answer.

Comment: Edited to accommodate `$q.race()`, with thanks to @georgeawg.

Answer (score -1):

Assign already created deferred.
Try and change this line:

<s>`self.deferReturn =  $q.defer();`</s>

`self.deferReturn = d;`