# Angular logs error to console before raising promise.catch

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I feel like I am going a little crazy, but Angular appears to throw an error for a promise even if I have a `catch` defined. It throws the error to the console, then allows the `catch` to run.

Here is a [super-simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91ukzzgg/)

The test code:

```
$q.when(1)
    .then(function() {
        throw new Error("test");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error caught', error);
    });
```

The resulting console

[image]
(dirty liar!)

Here is [a fiddle showing what I expect to happen](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i6ib6y1v/): the `catch` is raised, and no other error is logged to the console. Did I fail to configure something, or does Angular implement a broken promise spec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

angular by default logs all errors to console.

angular also provides a way to override this behavior. `$exceptionHandler` is a global service that is given a chance to process any exceptions ($http, errors during $digest, etc).

If you add this piece of code:

```
myApp.factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
    //throw exception;
  };
});
```

Then all errors would just stop further logging. Would process catch() handlers though. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jjx5rn3/

UPDATE:

As pointed by `dnc253` in the comments, there's a better way if you intend to actually override an angularjs service. Even not being the focus of this question, it's better to know that simply declaring a service with the same name, in whatever module, the service is fully replaced (last-in wins). If one wants to add functionality around the original service, a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) is the right choice.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but a decorator is preferred over overwriting the whole service. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595469/how-to-override-exceptionhandler-implementation

Comment: But shoudln't the exception not even get to this point? Shouldn't it have been handled by the `catch`?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg The `catch` happens after the handling that happens in this method. That's why it shows up in the console first